# How to read data from HttpPost object?

Tags: android, web-services

I am sending a request to a webservice along with a string as a parameter using POST method.

For Example:-

```
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(http://www.google.com/gmail/getpictures.php);//sample URL (not working)
```

I am also sending a string along with web service URL

```
tmp = new StringEntity(data,"UTF-8");//data is any string
tmp.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader("Content-type", "application/json"));
httpPost.setEntity(tmp);
```

I send the request using

```
response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
```

I want to print what is inside the httpPost object, to know if I am sending the right data to the server.
**HttpPost.toString()** is not working for me.  Anyone know how to retrive httpPost object into a string so that I can print it on **LOGCAT**?

Comment: Question is bit strange. You are sending JSON data in data object. What exactly you want to see ? Format the request sent to server ?

Comment: Ya It is strange. actually I am sending a SQL Query as a string to the server along with its URL. But I am getting response as fail. So I want to see is I am sending a query in correct way or not? SO i want to see it on logcat before                              response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

Comment: ok. The problem is your string which contains space. http://www.androidhive.info/2011/10/android-making-http-requests/ This will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to getContent from response.

```
InputStream inputstream = response.getEntity().getContent();
BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputstream));
```

now read data from rd.

Comment: I know that.But It is a response ,I want to print the data which is i am sending not which i am getting from response.I dont know Whether I am sending data in correct way or not?

Comment: then just check on server whether its written correctly or not..
or after sending again receive data and check it.

Comment: I am getting response as Fail.

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
DefaultHttpClient hc = new DefaultHttpClient();
                                            ResponseHandler<String> res = new BasicResponseHandler();
String response = hc.execute(postMethod,res);
System.out.println(responce);
```

Comment: See.I am not intrested in response data. I am intrested in data which i am sending.Whether it is correct way or not.  from Your code I want to print data of hc object    not of response.

Comment: if the response from server is correct then you send correct data otherwise wrong

Comment: Thats why I want to check it before sending.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
String response = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);
```